# Datetimepicker does not display default date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need to display the default date in all the fields, but when I added the plugins option `minDate: new Date()`, but the dates in the fields are not displayed, but the value is internally there in the field.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

**Code:**

```js
$(function(){
  $('.date').each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
          minDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ignoreReadonly: true,
          useCurrent: false
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean useCurrent: false ?

Comment: have you tried changing this : ```ignoreReadonly: true,``` to false

Comment: useCurrent Set the start date when you open the window with the dates

Comment: I changed to true but it works for me in the script, but in my script it may be that I have many libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Try using the **defaultDate** property instead.</s>

EDIT:
I understand the problem more now, and it turns out some of the properties you were setting were complicating the problem.

It also seems like you're just bypassing the `readonly` attribute so you could remove that and that would simplify the initialization even further. (And the `value="2017-01-01"` attributes aren't doing anything except confusing what the inputs actual values are)

```js
$(function(){
  $('.date').each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
          minDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ignoreReadonly: true
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly  value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly  value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Removing the minDate option all dates are available

Comment: @Learningandsharing Did you want the default value to be the value present on the inputs (2017-01-01) or the current day?

Comment: The value of the current date, and that all dates before the current day are disabled

Comment: @Learningandsharing Ah okay, I understand now. I've updated my answer to fix this and explain a bit further.

Comment: Thank you very much blessings

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.date').each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ignoreReadonly: true,
          useCurrent: false,
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          minDate: new Date()
          });
      });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more detail visit [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#defaultdate)

Comment: Removing the minDate option all dates are available

Answer (score 1):

It should be added to @Peter's answer that if `minDate` is set as `new Date()` after clicking other date and try to select again today's date it won't be possible, you can solve this using:

```
minDate: moment().startOf('day')
```

[Momentjs document of startOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

```js
$(function(){
  $('.date').each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
          minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ignoreReadonly: true
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly  value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly  value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```